# Как заставить работать if после нажатия на одну из кнопок?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

После нажатия на одну из кнопок должен срабатывать `if`. Ещё планируется, что в `if` будут вложены другие `if`. Все `if` зависят от нажатия на одну из кнопок.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
        
arg = 0
def click(arg):
    if arg == 1:
        return True
    elif arg == 2:
        return False
        
lbl = Label(text='Дрова')
        
btn = Button(text="Yes", command=click(1))
btn1 = Button(text="No", command=click(2))
        
lbl.pack()
btn.pack()
btn.pack()

if click(arg) == True:
    lbl.config(text='Тутуруту')
    if click(arg) == True:
        lbl.config(text='Следующий вопрос')
        if click(arg) == True:
            lbl.config(text='И так далее пока блок схема не кончится')
    elif click(arg) == False:
        lbl.config(text='Тут что-нибудь')
elif click(arg) == False:
    lbl.config(text='А вот и нет...')
        
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто через if не получится, т.к. программа с графическим интерфейсом работает не линейно (как в консоли), а управляется событиями (например, нажатиями кнопок, как в данном случае). Поэтому нужно как-то представить весь опрос/викторину в виде графа или дерева, помнить в каком месте графа в данный момент вы находитесь, а нажатия на кнопок будут изменять положение в этом графе. Гуглить по теме: конечные автоматы, машины состояний.

Как я понимаю, возврата по опросу в обратную сторону не предполагается, поэтому его можно представить в виде дерева. Дерево можно составить из простых кортежей, где первый элемент - вопрос, второй элемент - следующий узел/вопрос, если ответ был да, третий элемент - следующий узел/вопрос, если ответ был нет. Для конечных узлов можно использовать просто строки или `None`.

Простейшее дерево:

```
(
   "Вопрос?",
   "Правильно!",
   "Неправильно!",
)
```

Более сложный опрос:

```
(
   "Вопрос?",
   (
       "Правильно! А если так?",
       "Неправильно! Вы проиграли!",
       "Правильно! Вы выиграли!"
   ),
   "Неправильно! Вы проиграли!"
)
```

Для вашего кода получается такое дерево:

```
(
    'Дрова',
    (
        'Тутуруту',
        (
            'Следующий вопрос',
            'И так далее пока блок схема не кончится',
            None
        ),
        'Тут что-нибудь'
    ),
    'А вот и нет...'
)
```

Дальше код:

```
from tkinter import *

quiz = (
    'Дрова',
    (
        'Тутуруту',
        (
            'Следующий вопрос',
            'И так далее пока блок схема не кончится',
            None
        ),
        'Тут что-нибудь'
    ),
    'А вот и нет...'
)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')


def end_game():
    # Действия, если опрос окончен (тут просто скрываем кнопки)
    btn.pack_forget()
    btn1.pack_forget()


def show_question():
    if position is None:  # Если вместо следующего вопроса оказалось None
        lbl.config(text="Конец")
        end_game()
    elif isinstance(position, str):  # Если вместо следующего вопроса оказалась строка
        lbl.config(text=position)
        end_game()
    else:
        lbl.config(text=position[0])


def click(answer):
    # Внутри функции меняем глобальную переменную позиции, поэтому нужно объявить ее как глобальную
    global position  

    # Если "Да", то переход по первой ветке дерева, если "Нет" - то по другой
    if answer:
        position = position[1]
    else:
        position = position[2]
    
    show_question()


lbl = Label()

# Тут вызовы функций нужно обернуть в лямбды, иначе функция будет вызываться сразу при старте программы
btn = Button(text="Yes", command=lambda: click(True))
btn1 = Button(text="No", command=lambda: click(False))
        
lbl.pack()
btn.pack()
btn1.pack()

position = quiz  # Устанавливаем начальную позицию на "корень" дерева
show_question()  # Показываем первый вопрос
        
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Не, ну почему через if не получится? Можно использовать `wait_variable`. Но это костыль.

Comment: @GrAnd если честно, впервые слышу про `wait_variable`. Ну да, наверное можно в начале ожидания ставить `BooleanVar` в `False`, при нажатии на кнопку менять на `True` и в какую-то глобальную переменную записывать ответ (если просто ответ записывать, то например два `True` подряд по идее не будут считаться изменением состояния переменной).